# Horizontal scroll bar js html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal scroll bar which will therefore replace the browser default one (the one on the right), which shows the position of the page. But I can't find anything on the web. Can someone help me?

I have only found scrollbars to insert into a div to scroll some text

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you style the default scroll bar with css?

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_scrollbars_styling)

or

[w3 school docs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)
If your want to change the scroll bar of whole website then directly use

```css
::webkit-scroll-bar{
width:5px;
/*other stuffs*/
}
```

Comment: I would like to delete the default bar and add one